# What is the probability that in a game of bridge you receive 5 spades and your partner 8?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that in a game of bridge you receive 5 spades and your partner the remaining spades?

Ithought of using the binomial distribution for that but i didn't get the right answer.

So i know that the total of hands possible is $\frac{52!}{\left ( 13! \right )^4}$

but after that im kind of confused, i tried all sort of thing but nothing seems to give me the right answer.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would help me alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine (it does not matter, but this is not the way bridge hands are dealt) that you get $13$ cards, and then your partner gets $13$.

The probability that you get $5$ spades (and therefore $8$ non-spades) is equal to
$$\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{8}}{\binom{52}{13}}.$$
**Given** that you got $5$ spades, the probability your partner gets $8$ is
$$\frac{\binom{8}{8}\binom{31}{5}}{\binom{39}{13}}.$$
Multiply.

**Remark:** The binomial distribution is not suitable, since we are sampling from the deck of cards without replacement.

Comment: oh. that easy... i feel dumb heh, thank you

Comment: You are welcome, it is a matter of counting, and concentrating on your hand and your partner's. It is hypergeometric ideas that are relevant.